# clojure jdbc & postgres: could not determine data type of parameter $1 when creating view

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I'm trying to create a view like so:

```
(jdbc/execute! db ["create view fruit as select ? as type" "apple"])
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

How can I create my view?

If I inline the parameter, it works, so I'm guessing it's some problem with prepared statments.
Inlining the parameter is not an option though as the input is from a website and not trusted.

Comment: what happens if you run this query manually "select 'apple' as type" is not a valid SQL statement, if I recall correctly

Comment: seems like invalid statement, you can use format (format "create view fruit as select %s as type" "name") if VIEW is not supported with params.

Comment: @a.k indeed that would work, but it'd leave me vulneable to SQL injections and the like so not a good solution in my case